# Is rendering with a shader in to a texture for use in another shader going to work well in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, glsl, shader

I am working on a GPU physics simulation of fluid for a university project. I am a physicist but and I am not a very experienced coder, especially when it comes to GPU and OpenGL. I have made my simulation on CPU and now trying to port it to GPU. It is a 2D simulation of a fluid.

Given my inexperience with OpenGL and general inexperience with coding graphics I chose to use SpriteKit, as it allows me just to create a sprite, assign a shader in a few lines of code and write my simulation in the shader. One thing I find not obvious is how do I render out the result of one of my calculations to use it in the next one. For example I calculate pressure in a shader and then use it to calculate velocity in the next shader.

```
renderSprite.shader = PressureShader;
SKTexture *texture = [[self view] textureFromNode:[self scene]];
[renderSprite setTexture:texture];
//Make an SKUniform here, load all the data needed in to SKUniform 
renderSprite.shader = VelocityShader;
```

Is this the right way to do it and is going to be efficient? Or is SpriteKit not fitted for such use at all and I should be using something else? It looks right but I have a feeling this could be very slow. I would also appreciate any recommendations of a different API/Framework I could use for this (especially if it is easy to learn).

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem? This is an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you don't. The use you describe is not what SpriteKit was made for and it is not supported. You would be better off just coding this type of approach directly in Metal, I would avoid OpenGL if I were you, it is honestly just too complex. A link to an actual working framework that does exactly what you need can be found [here](http://metalbyexample.com/fundamentals-of-image-processing/).